# Google Map Direction API Return Zero Results Swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-api-2

My App using Google Maps **Direction** API to draw route between any two positions (origin - direction positions)user pin it.

I used the API like this way:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=(fromLat),(fromLng)&destination=(toLat),(toLng)&mode=(travelMode)&departure_time=now&alternatives=true&language=(lang)

The problem is sometimes the response return Zero Results, like this :

```
{
  "geocoded_waypoints": [
    {},
    {}
  ],

  "routes": [],

  "status": "ZERO_RESULTS"
}
```

I searched a lot but no useful results.

Anyone faced this problem?

Could this problem be because I used the free API?

I will be thankful for any help.

Thanks.

Comment: If it fails only some times, isn't there a possibility that there is in fact no route? You can't search for something that's not there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there will be no path then it returns the same.

See this link : [Path Information](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=23.033863,72.585022&destination=22.055,72.565022&sensor=false)

Hope this helps!

**UPDATE:**

Try to covert latitude-longitude into address and pass it over the URL and it will solve the issue.
`CLGeocoder` might help you to do the same.

Comment: no, when i try the same positions on googleMaps website, it give me a route

Comment: could you pass some more information, like which link you are accessing

Comment: this is the link : 
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=18.6548634,33.097382&destination=36.7547311,30.3368614&mode=Driving&language=en

Comment: Well create a Address from the latitude and longitude and pass that into the link: like this https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=River+Nile&destination=Antalya+Turkey&mode=Driving&language=en

Comment: when I tured the lat, lng into address it works! so strange :S, Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

It's because of wrong lat-long for the destination. Also path is not available for the requested Travel mode.

Comment: change the travel mode.

Comment: when path not available for the requested Travel mode the response tell me that and give me the available travel modes.

Comment: In my case I am using address instead of lat-long and it's working fine.

Comment: Also you can use this class for geocoding and reverse geocode for the same. https://github.com/lminhtm/LMGeocoder

Answer (score 1):

Try with this google API:

[https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%@,%@&daddr=%@,%@](http://Route%20the%20Path)

Pass latitude, longitudes to above API. You will get the result.

Comment: where I pass the lats, lngs? in saddr, daddr

Comment: saddr is Start point and daddr is destination point.    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%f,%f",self.startinglatitude,self.startinglongitude,self.destinationlatitude,self.destinationlongitude]

Comment: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%f,%f",self.startinglatitude,self.startinglongitude,self.destinationlatitude,self.destinationlongitude]

Answer (score 0):

The result is zero because the issue is with the API. Use correct API through the google maps documentation for **Directions API** [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/overview). Please avoid using the api's provided in the stack overflow as they are outdated.

Good Luck!