# Google map distance api give give status = "ZERO_RESULTS" in case of destination is out of india

Tags: ios

i am hitting a google api to find out the distance between source and destination to draw a route on map it is working fine if the both of the addresses (source and destination is in India ) but it gives the result

```
{
    "destination_addresses" =     (
        "25.224551,55.165524"
    );
    "origin_addresses" =     (
        "28.501944,77.085457"
    );
    rows =     (
                {
            elements =             (
                                {
                    status = "ZERO_RESULTS";
                }
            );
        }
    );
    status = OK;
}
```

when i put the destination as out of the country
  this is my sample code

```
-(void)GetDistance{


NSString * urlString=@"";
if ([[eventBeforeOneDay valueForKey:@"latitude"] doubleValue]>0) {
    urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=%@,%@&destinations=%f,%f&sensor=false",[eventBeforeOneDay valueForKey:@"latitude"],[eventBeforeOneDay valueForKey:@"longitude"],UIAPPDelegate.googlePlaceAddEvent.coordinate.latitude,UIAPPDelegate.googlePlaceAddEvent.coordinate.longitude];
}else
     urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=%f,%f&destinations=%f,%f&sensor=false",UIAPPDelegate.UniversalCoOrdinate.latitude,UIAPPDelegate.UniversalCoOrdinate.longitude,UIAPPDelegate.googlePlaceAddEvent.coordinate.latitude,UIAPPDelegate.googlePlaceAddEvent.coordinate.longitude];



NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

// Prepare the request
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Data-Type"];

NSError *errorReturned = nil;
NSURLResponse *theResponse =[[NSURLResponse alloc]init];
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request   returningResponse:&theResponse error:&errorReturned];
if (data != nil) {
    NSDictionary* responseDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&errorReturned];
    if ([[[[[[[responseDict valueForKey:@"rows"] objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"elements"] objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"distance"] valueForKey:@"value"] integerValue] > 100000 ){

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"pushImage" object:jsonMohit];
    }

}
}
```

and this is my url

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=28.501944,77.085457&destinations=25.224551,55.165524&sensor=false

if any one has any idea then please help me out. Thanx in advance.

Comment: @ Ranveer Singh check out this post https://stackoverflow.com/q/37786919/6458723

Comment: It's not easy to get to an island near Dubai from India.

Comment: https://www.google.com/maps/dir/25.224551,55.165524/'28.501944,77.085457'/@26.7883012,61.6646346,6z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m6!4m5!1m0!1m3!2m2!1d77.085457!2d28.501944 ? Only by Flight. Maybe a restriction.